# Push Notification : what is the condition to be count as a "spamming"

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm implementing server-to-client communication in my iOS Application. What I'm trying to do is to deliver new messages from server to client such as

- Old version will be no longer support soon, please update asap.
- There is a new content available.
- Reminder of some interesting content.

etc.

When device got message, it will notify user by showing "You got new X messages" with badge number. After user launch the app by clicking at the notification message, it will show those message containing images and text within my application.

At the beginning, I did this by **iOS 7 background data fetch** because the message content size that I mentioned will contains image url and text, it may exceed the maximum size of push notification content length. After testing with that approach, I found that there is no guarantee of when the application will be wake to connect and fetch new message from my server. (I left the device overnight to see how many time it connect to my server, first night was 5 times, second night was once)

Since some of the message is time sensitive (like reminder), I came up with the another approach by sending a Push Notification to the device when there is any new message to signal the app instead. But, according to App Store Review Guideline

```
5. Push Notifications
  5.6 Apps cannot use Push Notifications to send advertising, 
      promotions, or direct marketing of any kind
  5.8 Apps that excessively use the network capacity or bandwidth 
      of the APN service or unduly burden a device with Push Notifications 
      will be rejected
```

So, my questions are,

- If I send a message contains promotions or marketing material but it won't showing at the iOS Device home screen, instead, user has to launch my application to see those contents, will it be the case of 5.6?
- From 5.8, "excessively use the network capacity or bandwidth", do you know how many notifications can be sent to how many devices per time period? If I send 2 notifications to thousands of devices every hour, will that be the case?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: 5.6 wont be a problem, because i developed few which is working as like your senario and they are live in app store.
5.8 also wont be problem i think, because i saw few application using push notification for voice call and video call application for intimate new call arrival for the user.

Comment: Are you sure about this, I really don't want to risk being pull out from the App Store after few months. My boss will definitely not happy with that.

If you are certain about this, please add an answer, I can't upvote or mark this as correct answer.

Comment: Probably apple wont remove the app from app store after approval for this kind of reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**5.6** wont be a problem, because i developed few which is working as like your scenario and they are live in app store.

**5.8** also wont be problem i think, because i saw few application using push notification for ***voice call and video call application for intimate new call arrival*** for the user.

> Some chatting application also using APN for intimation the user when
>   new message arrived for that user.

Comment: Can you name one for your app (or another app that you know) that pass the qualification of 5.6 so that I can download and see how it works. Marketing material is the main reason of this implementation.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/ag/app/h.t.-hackney/id612881041?mt=8 try this one they using APN to intimate all of their user when updating their promotion and event. Also look into Neighborhood Barre from the same developer they also using APN for promotion purpose.